# Proving the limit of $\lim_{x \to 0} x f(x) = 0$ through squeeze theorem

Tags: limits

I have the next function:

### $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1,&\text{if }|x|\ge 1\\|x|,&\text{if }|x| <1\;.\end{cases}$$
Prove:
$\lim_{x \to 0} x f(x) = 0$ using squeeze theorem:

I'm not sure if my work is correct:

Squeeze theorem:
\begin{align*}
    g(x) \le &f(x) \le h(x)\\
    \lim_{x \to a} g(x) &= L \lim_{x \to a} h(x) \\
    \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to a}f(x)&=L
\end{align*}
I'll break the limit in two (just to work better).
\begin{align*}
  \lim_{x \to 0}x \cdot \underbrace{\lim_{x \to 0}|x|}_{\text{bounded function}}
\end{align*}
Function $|x|$ is bounded as:
\begin{align*}
-1<|x|<1\\
\text{Multiplying by x:}\\
\underbrace{-x}_{g(x)}< \underbrace{|x|\cdot x}_{f(x)} < \underbrace{x}_{h(x)}\\
\end{align*}
And I know:
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{x \to 0} g(x) = \lim_{x \to 0} (-x) =0\\
&\lim_{x \to 0} h(x) = \lim_{x \to 0} x =0
\end{align*}

### So:
\begin{align*}
    f(x)=|x| \cdot x = 0 
\end{align*}
$\lim_{x \to 0} |x| \cdot x = 0$

I'm not sure about this, because the other thing I did was:
\begin{align*}
-1&<x<1 \text{(multiplying by x)}\\
-x &< x^2 < x \\
\lim_{x \to 0} -x &< \lim_{x \to 0} x^2 < \lim_{x \to 0}
x 
\end{align*}

I'm not sure about that $x^2$

Need some help to guide my work :(

Comment: You have some mistakes in how you've written out the definition of the squeeze thm but it looks like they're typos and that you understand it. It should be $g\le f \le h \Rightarrow \lim g \le \lim f \le \lim h \Rightarrow \lim g = \lim f = \lim h$.

Comment: When you multiply by $ x$ ,you must distinguish two cases $x>0$ $x\le 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

We want the limit near zero, so we need the expression of $ f(x)$ in $(-1,1)$ which is $ |x|$.

We have

$$\forall x\in (-1,1) -1<x<1\implies$$

$$\forall x\in(-1,1) -|x|\le x|x| \le |x| \implies$$
$$\forall x\in (-1,1)\;\; -|x|\le xf(x) \le |x|$$

Answer (score 1):

Your proof seems overall fine but could do with being more concise and needs some things removed. For instance, it is not true that $f(x)=|x|\cdot x =0$. Instead, you should have $\lim x f(x) = \lim |x| \cdot x = 0$. Do not confuse the limit for the function itself. Also, your section at the end bounding $\lim x^2$ seems irrelevant and doesn't aid the proof. Lastly, I think you should an explicit justification that we can find $\lim xf(x)$ by looking at $\lim x |x|$. In other words, that $f(x)=|x|$ around $0$. Hamam's answer has this as *"the expression of $f(x)$ in $(-1,1) $ is $|x|$"*.

A more pressing issue is that your argument that $-1<|x|<1\Rightarrow -x<|x|\cdot x<x$ is not generally correct. If $x<0$, multiplying the inequality by $x$ would *reverse* the inequality. For example, $-1<|-0.5|<1$ but it is **not** true that $\underbrace{-(-0.5)}_{0.5} < \underbrace{|-0.5|\cdot -0.5}_{-0.25} < -0.5$. Consider changing the lower bound of $-1$ to a different constant that wouldn't switch the inequality (hint: not a negative one).

Answer (score 0):

Notice that for all $x$,

$$0\le f(x)\le|x|$$ so that the squeezing is

$$0\le|x\,f(x)|\le x^2.$$

---

In fact you shouldn't even worry about $f(x)$ for $|x|\ge1$, because you can always take $\delta <1$.